# Tool for convert multi files vimrc into single file

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, neovim, multiple-files

i try to collect my .vimrc files into single file is there anyway to generate single file using vimscript depending on `source` vimscript keyword or python code

example of my .vimrc

```
if isdirectory($HOME."/.config/vim/")
  for configfile in split(glob($HOME."/.config/vim/*.vim"), "\n")
    execute "source " configfile
  endfor
endif
```

i put vim configs in separated files under `~/.config/vim/` directory and source them from .vimrc file

Comment: You'd need to do the check by `source` recursively; worse, if you really want *everything*, you'd have to read in everything under `plugin`, and all the other stuff grouped in appropriate autocommands, etc. This is hard to get right, and I confess I don't see the point. The structure of `.vim` and `:help runtimepath` is there for a reason

Comment: Please [edit] add more details to clarify what it is you are trying to accomplish: There is only one vimrc file. But you mention multiple and the source command. Could you give an example layout that you are trying to collapse together? (Welcome to [vi.se], by the way!)

Comment: Well, for that I would do one of two things: `find ~/.config/vim -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cat > ~/.vim/vimrc`, or put them in `~/.vim/plugin` where they will be sourced automatically after your vimrc.

Comment: well, thanks for answering me, but this not work if the files that i source also source other files the output file of this command ```find ~/.config/vim -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cat > ~/.vim/vimrc``` will include source statement

Comment: I wonder how many sourced files are there if you even need to develop a new tool only to paste them together once. And what is good in pasting so many files into a single monster script.

Comment: there are about 20 file, i need to put them into single file so it will be easy to share and post it on github gist.

Comment: You can remove the sources with something like `:g/source/d` afterwards?